# Convert codes to faster codes using Groupby

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I need to return value in this format:

Find the news using their category and choose from each category 6 news

```
 Category :
          news
          news
          news
          news
          news
          news
 Category :
          news
          news
          news
          news
          news
          news
 Category :
          news
          news
          news
          news
          news
          news
```

I've written this code but it's very slow.

```
private async Task<List<NewsDto>> GetCatNews()
{
    List<NewsDto> news = new List<NewsDto>();
    var FindAllCategory = this.CategoryService.Entities.ToList();
    foreach (var item in FindAllCategory)
    {
        var model = new NewsDto();
        var TakNews = Entities.Where(x => x.CategoryId == item.Id).Take(6)
            .OrderBy(x => x.CreateDate).ToList();
        if (TakNews.Count >= 6)
        {
            news.Add(new NewsDto
            {
                CatId = item.Id,
                CatName = item.Name,
                NewsContents = await AddNewsContents(TakNews)
            });
        }
    }
    return news;
}

public async Task<List<NewsContent>> AddNewsContents(List<Post> TakNews)
{
    List<NewsContent> newsContents = new List<NewsContent>();
    foreach (var addNews in TakNews)
    {
        newsContents.Add(new NewsContent
        {
            Description = addNews.Description,
            Id = addNews.Id,
            ImagePath = rootSiteData.GetNewPath() + '/' + addNews.ImagePath,
            Title = addNews.Title
        });
    }
    return newsContents;
}
```

I need to write faster code for up performance in project .

**How can I solve this problem?**

**Sample Data :**

i except return this value

iexcept return this value

```
"data": [
{
  "catId": 1,
  "catName": "سیاسی",
  "newsContents": [
    {
      "id": 3048,
      "imagePath": "https://localhost:44372/Uplaod/NewsPictureFolder/NewsMainPicture/509246904089447.jpg",
      "title": "نفت در برابر غذا! / حقایق تلخ اینستکس چیست؟ ا",
      "description": "اروپایی‌ها بعد از ۹ ماه تعلل و مذاکره و ۴ ماه پس از اعلام تصمیم‌شان برای مقابله با تحریم‌های ثانویه امریکا یک ساز و کار با ظرفیت محدود آن هم نه برای تبادل پول بلکه برای تامین غذا و دارو ایجاد کرده اند.\n"
    },
    {
      "id": 3049,
      "imagePath": "https://localhost:44372/Uplaod/NewsPictureFolder/NewsMainPicture/349512794187136.jpg",
      "title": "پاسخ ایران به ادعای آمریکا در رابطه با بروز تنش در منطقه",
      "description": "نمایندگی ایران در سازمان ملل، ادعاها اخیر آمریکا از جمله دستور تخلیه کارمندان غیرضروری این کشور در عراق را آخرین پرده از جنگ تبلیغاتی آمریکا علیه ایران با استفاده از \"گزارش‌های اطلاعاتی تقلبی\"دانست که به منظور بهانه شروع یک درگیری احتمالی بیان می‌شود.\n"
    },
    {
      "id": 3050,
      "imagePath": "https://localhost:44372/Uplaod/NewsPictureFolder/NewsMainPicture/946066292956619.jpg",
      "title": "به زودی احکام افزایش دستمزد کارمندان ابلاغ می‌شود",
      "description": "تسنیم نوشت: نماینده همدان در مجلس از نشست مشترک دولت، مجلس و دیوان محاسبات برای تعیین تکلیف حقوق و دستمزد کارمندان خبر داد.\n\n"
    },
    {
      "id": 3051,
      "imagePath": "https://localhost:44372/Uplaod/NewsPictureFolder/NewsMainPicture/322083917213095.jpg",
      "title": "عصبانیت شدید ترامپ از سیاست های بولتون و ترامپ در قبال ایران",
      "description": "روزنامه واشنگتن پست به نقل از چند مقام آمریکایی گزارش داد دونالد ترامپ از مشاوران ارشدی که به نظر وی ایالات متحده را به سوی تقابل با ایران می برند ناراضی و ناامید شده و او به دنبال گفت وگو با ایران است."
    },
    {
      "id": 3052,
      "imagePath": "https://localhost:44372/Uplaod/NewsPictureFolder/NewsMainPicture/322083917213095.jpg.jpg",
      "title": "اقدامات ایران غرب را پشیمان خواهد کرد",
      "description": "عضو شورای مرکزی حزب موتلفه اسلامی گفت: آمریکایی‌ها در برجام بد عهدی کردند و از آن خارج شدند، لذا مذاکره با آمریکا تعطیل است."
    },
    {
      "id": 3053,
      "imagePath": "https://localhost:44372/Uplaod/NewsPictureFolder/NewsMainPicture/215729472154856.jpg",
      "title": "ایران در برابر آمریکا باید سیاست تهاجمی به کار گیرد",
      "description": "نایب رییس جبهه پیروان خط امام و رهبری گفت: باید در سالگرد خروج آمریکا از برجام سیاست تهاجمی به کار گیریم و خیلی پذیرفته نیست که در برابر آمریکایی‌ها منفعل باشیم.\n"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "catId": 14,
  "catName": "ورزشی",
  "newsContents": [
    {
      "id": 3042,
      "imagePath": "https://localhost:44372/Uplaod/NewsPictureFolder/NewsMainPicture/226736856824855.jpeg",
      "title": "همه احتمالات درباره قفس توری ” استقلال ” ؛ وضعیت رحمتی و حسینی چگونه خواهد بود ؟",
      "description": "استقلال در ادوار مختلف دروازه‌بان‌های خوبی داشته و در خیلی سال‌ها کیفیت خوب هر دو دروازه‌بان از نظر فنی به نفع تیم بوده، اما مشکلات زیادی هم درست کرده است.\n\n"
    },
    {
      "id": 3043,
      "imagePath": "https://localhost:44372/Uplaod/NewsPictureFolder/NewsMainPicture/21463635040650.jpg",
      "title": "پرسپولیس ستاره استقلال را به صورت رسمی جذب کرد",
      "description": "به گزارش گروه ورزشی خبرگزاری برنا؛ با نظر مثبت برانکو، ساسان زمانه، دروازه بان تیم امید استقلال به صورت رسمی به تیم فوتبال پرسپولیس پیوست.\n\n"
    },
    {
      "id": 3044,
      "imagePath": "https://localhost:44372/Uplaod/NewsPictureFolder/NewsMainPicture/836138365621559.jpg",
      "title": "یک میلیارد به من بدهید استقلال را قهرمان کنم",
      "description": "گلر سابق استقلال نسبت به شرایط کنونی این تیم ناراضی است و از بازیکنان گلایه دارد.\n\n"
    },
    {
      "id": 3045,
      "imagePath": "https://localhost:44372/Uplaod/NewsPictureFolder/NewsMainPicture/622410699584925.jpg",
      "title": "مهره ثابت برانکو رفتنی شد",
      "description": " فصل نقل‌وانتقالات از همین حالا برای باشگاه پرسپولیس آغاز شده است."
    },
    {
      "id": 3046,
      "imagePath": "https://localhost:44372/Uplaod/NewsPictureFolder/NewsMainPicture/130684227374618.jpg",
      "title": "سکوی قهرمانی پرسپولیس در حال آماده‌سازی",
      "description": "به گزارش شریان نیوز،پرسپولیس در آستانه قهرمانی لیگ برتر قرار دارد.\n\n"
    },
    {
      "id": 3047,
      "imagePath": "https://localhost:44372/Uplaod/NewsPictureFolder/NewsMainPicture/149180200034218.jpg",
      "title": "سلطانی‌فر: زیر سؤال بردن همه چیز با یک شکست، عین بی‌انصافی و بی‌عدالتی است",
      "description": "مسعود سلطانی‌فر، وزیر ورزش و جوانان گفت: اینکه هر کسی شکست بخورد و بخواهد همه چیز را زیر سؤال ببرد، عین بی‌انصافی و بی‌عدالتی است.\n"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "catId": 1011,
  "catName": "فناوری",
  "newsContents": [
    {
      "id": 3054,
      "imagePath": "https://localhost:44372/Uplaod/NewsPictureFolder/NewsMainPicture/458855903672103.jpg",
      "title": "دستیابی به فرمولاسیون بزاق زالو برای ترمیم زخم",
      "description": "محققان کشور درصدد هستند تا فرمولاسیون سرم و کرمی که از بزاق زالوی ایرانی به دست آورده اند را برای ترمیم زخم به کار ببرند.\n\n"
    },
    {
      "id": 3055,
      "imagePath": "https://localhost:44372/Uplaod/NewsPictureFolder/NewsMainPicture/5412820294475.jpg",
      "title": "آزمایش موفقیت آمیز سپر دفاعی ایرانی برای خنثی کردن «استاکس‌نت»",
      "description": "وزیر ارتباطات و فناوری اطلاعات از موفقیت‌آمیز بودن آزمایش سپر دفاعی (فایروال) برای سیستم‌های اتوماسیون صنعتی که از سوی دانشمندان جوان ایران ساخته شده، خبر داد.\n\n"
    },
    {
      "id": 3056,
      "imagePath": "https://localhost:44372/Uplaod/NewsPictureFolder/NewsMainPicture/135842434489640.jpg",
      "title": "شرکت های فناوری در برابر محتوای خشونت آمیز اینترنت متعهد شدند",
      "description": "طرح «کریستی چرچ» در اجلاسی با حضور رهبران ۹ کشور و نمایندگان شرکت های فناوری امضا شد. در این سند قانونی شرکت‌های فناوری از جمله فیس بوک، توئیتر، گوگل به اقدامات خاص متعهد شدند.\n\n"
    },
    {
      "id": 3057,
      "imagePath": "https://localhost:44372/Uplaod/NewsPictureFolder/NewsMainPicture/364654025412296.jpg",
      "title": "عملکرد مناطق ویژه علم و فناوری بازنگری می شود",
      "description": "دبیرکل شورای عالی علوم تحقیقات و فناوری با بیان اینکه عملکرد مناطق ویژه علم و فناوری خوب نبوده گفت: عملکرد این مناطق مورد بازنگری قرار می گیرد.\n\n"
    },
    {
      "id": 3058,
      "imagePath": "https://localhost:44372/Uplaod/NewsPictureFolder/NewsMainPicture/157874084121194.jpg",
      "title": "تاکسی هوایی آلمانی برای نخستین بار آزمایش شد",
      "description": "نخستین آزمایش تاکسی هوایی متعلق به شرکت آلمانی لیلیوم انجام شد. این تاکسی هوایی الکتریکی ۳۶ موتور دارد و به طور عمودی از زمین بلند می شود و فرود می آید."
    },
    {
      "id": 3059,
      "imagePath": "https://localhost:44372/Uplaod/NewsPictureFolder/NewsMainPicture/236575355911763.jpg",
      "title": "مایکروسافت مجبور به وصله کردن ویندوزهای از رده خارج شد",
      "description": "اگر چه مایکروسافت سالهاست دیگر از ویندوز ایکس پی پشتیبانی نمی‌کند، اما خطرات روزافزون بدافزار واناکرای این شرکت را مجبور به پشتیبانی مجدد از ویندوزهای قدیمی کرده است."
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please could you clarify what you mean by the later attempt "not working"? Does it not compile? Does it throw an exception? Does it not return the values you want? What does it do?

Comment: @JonSkeet Ignore that part of the question.I think you can help me

Comment: @mr-dortaj which part of the code is slow? I think noone can help you speed up the database query itsself. Is it nessesarry that you're using async/await (is it an app with GUI?)

Comment: @Dominik using linq and loop = reduce speed in big data

Comment: @mr-dortaj can you put some stopwatches into your code and clarify which line / part has the biggest performance impact?

Comment: It would really help us if you'd give more details of the schema, along with some sample data and expected output. At the moment we'd have to do quite a lot of guesswork ourselves. (I'd also strongly encourage you to start following .NET naming conventions, e.g. `camelCase` for parameters and local variables.) Why is `AddNewsContents` asynchronous when it doesn't need to await anything? Aren't you getting a warning about that?

Comment: One thing to clarify: is every item in a category? And are all categories within `CategoryService.Entities`? If so, you're fetching *all* the entities, but via several queries. You could fetch them all in one go and do the grouping locally, which would at least make it faster. Using `var grouped = Entities.GroupBy(e => e.CategoryId)` would do the grouping in the database.

Comment: Ah - no, I see that you're only taking 6 items per category - although 6 random ones, given that the `OrderBy` comes *after* the `Take`. (Is that deliberate?)

Comment: Also it seems that you only use Id and Name of the category items. Maybe use Select to create an anonymous object with only those two properties: `this.CategoryService.Entities.Select(x => new { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name }).ToList()`. Hope this compiles, but i guess you get the point. This will reduce the data being selected from the DB and therefore could also save some performance, especially on a weak network.

Comment: `var TakNews = Entities.Where(x => x.CategoryId == item.Id).Take(6)
            .OrderBy(x => x.CreateDate).ToList()` for me it doesn't make any sence. Better to order by firstly and then take 6

Comment: @JonSkeet how can i order that . it show me`x.key`

Comment: I suggest you do some reading on LINQ groupings. The key would be the category ID - but each element of the group would be "the items with that category ID".

Comment: @JonSkeet It's about 2 days now that I'm thinking about this problem and I will not come up with a solution. Thank you for showing me the solution

Comment: @mr-dortaj As I think this discussion will end here, if you want to, you can add me on skype (itsdomi14) and we can talk about your problem in specific. Maybe debug it a bit and see what we can improve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm suspicious of what the "Entities" property in these classes returns. They could easily be returning materialized lists of all entities which effectively do a "SELECT *" from the database.

Start by simplifying the problem. Remove all unknowns, abstractions, and especially that async because from what I can read of this code it isn't leveraging async. Async is something that should be catered for after a sync solution is proven, it's not a silver bullet or a performance fix.

To fetch the oldest 6 news articles by category:

```
using (var context = new NewsDbContext())
{
    var categoriesWithNews = context.News.GroupBy(x => x.Category)
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Category = x.Key,
            News = x.OrderBy(n => n.CreatedDate).Take(6).ToList()
        }).ToList();
}
```

If you want the newest 6 news articles, then replace the `OrderBy` with `OrderByDescending`.

Depending on the number of categories this could still materialize a significant amount of data. Provided this is still reasonable, we can optimize this to select just the data we need rather than the entire entities:

```
var baseImagePath = rootSiteData.GetNewPath() + '/';
using (var context = new NewsDbContext())
{
    var data = context.News.GroupBy(x => x.Category)
        .Select(x => new
        {
            data = new 
            {
                CatId = x.Key.Id, 
                catName = x.Key.Name,
                newsContents = x.OrderBy(n => n.CreatedDate)
                .Select(n => new 
                {
                    id = n.Id,
                    imagePath = baseImagePath + n.ImagePath,
                    title = n.Title,
                    description = n.Description
                 }).Take(6).ToList()
        }).ToList();

    // Serialize data.
}
```

The above example uses anonymous types which should be sufficient if you just want to serialize the results. Alternatively you could use `Select` to populate your view models if that is what you want to return. (NewsContent, etc.)

The one last detail from your example was whether you want to exclude any category that doesn't have at least 6 news items under it. If this is a requirement, then add a `Where` clause before the final `ToList()`:

```
    var data = context.News.GroupBy(x => x.Category)
        .Select(x => new
        {
            data = new 
            {
                CatId = x.Key.Id, 
                catName = x.Key.Name,
                newsContents = x.OrderBy(n => n.CreatedDate)
                .Select(n => new 
                {
                    id = n.Id,
                    imagePath = baseImagePath + n.ImagePath,
                    title = n.Title,
                    description = n.Description
                 }).Take(6).ToList()
        })Where(x => x.newsContents.Count() == 6)
        .ToList();
```